# Enable both WiFi and Ethernet on Pi running Stretch

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on a project where a Raspberry Pi 3 runs a python server which controls some arduino's that are connected to the same router via a switch. I'm using a websocket to display a GUI in my browser.I need to be able to use the gui over my primary network connection which has internet acces. The situation looks like this : [image: how it should work]

The problem is that I can't get both WiFi and Ethernet to work, just one at a time. This has mainly to do with running Stretch, but downgrading is not an option. On older Raspbian version's I could use the **allow hotplug** or **auto** setting in the interfaces file to make sure both interfaces are up. But I've heard you should not touch the interfaces file on Stretch. Can someone tell me how to do it ?:) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly the same as in Jessie.

Comment: " But I've heard you should not touch the interfaces file on Stretch" is not useful advice - you may edit that file just as with any other versions of Debian

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is not related to software development.  Consider https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.